# Cannot Open Shared File Error in Netbeans | JavaFx FXML Application

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans, fxml, netbeans-plugins

I keep getting this Error whenever I compile my code:

```
Failed to load plugin /path/zulu/lib/libavplugin.so': libavcodec.so.55: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
```

However there is a file named libavplugin.so in lib folder. I am currently using Netbeans and the category of my project is javafx and the project is javafx with FXML Application.

Initially I was not able to create a javafx project with FXML Application as I was getting an Error of

```
 "Failed to automatically set up a JavaFX Platform".
```

So, I downloaded an open JDK from zulu and set up a non default JAVA platform. Now I am able create projects but code is not compiling.

I have looked over many stack overflow questions and I have also tried doing sudo ldconfig. Nothing is working for me.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Recent JavaFX versions [don’t use libavcodec 55](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8194065). Perhaps you are running obsolete software.